# How Box smart pointer is implemented?

Tags: rust

The current implementation looks like this:

```
pub struct Box<
T: ?Sized,
#[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")] A: Allocator = Global>(Unique<T>, A);

impl<T> Box<T> {


#[cfg(all(not(no_global_oom_handling)))]
#[inline(always)]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
#[must_use]
pub fn new(x: T) -> Self {
    #[rustc_box]
    Box::new(x)
}
```

Calling Box::new, does it not become recursive? Or is there any compiler magic going on?

Comment: The implementation `Box::new()` read `box x` until a few months ago. You can find [background information on the new implementation in this pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/97293).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Box expression have special compiler support](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nightly-rustc/rustc_monomorphize/collector/index.html#boxes)

> Since Box expression have special compiler support, no explicit calls to exchange_malloc() and box_free() may show up in MIR, even if the compiler will generate them. We have to observe Rvalue::Box expressions and Box-typed drop-statements for that purpose.

The `#[rustc_box]` expression will be turned into a call to `exchange_malloc` by compiler at [`build/expr/as_rvalue.rs#L112`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9f1a21ae2bd41b3dd335c44f38f29a1fb8712ddc/compiler/rustc_mir_build/src/build/expr/as_rvalue.rs#L112):

```rs
...
ExprKind::Box { value } => {
    ...
    // malloc some memory of suitable size and align:
    let exchange_malloc = Operand::function_handle(
        tcx,
        tcx.require_lang_item(LangItem::ExchangeMalloc, Some(expr_span)),
        ty::List::empty(),
        expr_span,
    );
    ...
}
```

The definition of [`exchange_malloc`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/033f93fbb98c3fb9bd09858f5b822789a4339de8/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs#L324) will be linked by the [`language_item_table`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/7cd4780c91139334b0a3a1f118b477506dd567dd/compiler/rustc_hir/src/lang_items.rs#L266):

```rs
/// The allocator for unique pointers.
#[cfg(all(not(no_global_oom_handling), not(test)))]
#[lang = "exchange_malloc"]
#[inline]
unsafe fn exchange_malloc(size: usize, align: usize) -> *mut u8 {
    let layout = unsafe { Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(size, align) };
    match Global.allocate(layout) {
        Ok(ptr) => ptr.as_mut_ptr(),
        Err(_) => handle_alloc_error(layout),
    }
}
```

At the end of `Box<T>` lifetime, [`box_free_block`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9f1a21ae2bd41b3dd335c44f38f29a1fb8712ddc/compiler/rustc_mir_dataflow/src/elaborate_drops.rs#L940) will be called and finally lead to `box_free`:

```rs
#[cfg_attr(not(test), lang = "box_free")]
#[inline]
#[rustc_const_unstable(feature = "const_box", issue = "92521")]
// This signature has to be the same as `Box`, otherwise an ICE will happen.
// When an additional parameter to `Box` is added (like `A: Allocator`), this has to be added here as
// well.
// For example if `Box` is changed to  `struct Box<T: ?Sized, A: Allocator>(Unique<T>, A)`,
// this function has to be changed to `fn box_free<T: ?Sized, A: Allocator>(Unique<T>, A)` as well.
pub(crate) const unsafe fn box_free<T: ?Sized, A: ~const Allocator + ~const Destruct>(
    ptr: Unique<T>,
    alloc: A,
) {
    unsafe {
        let size = size_of_val(ptr.as_ref());
        let align = min_align_of_val(ptr.as_ref());
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(size, align);
        alloc.deallocate(From::from(ptr.cast()), layout)
    }
}
```